# How to prevent a doo run if the ClojureScript compiler emits a warning

Tags: clojurescript, leiningen

I run some local continuous tests with `lein doo phantom test` but I am not well informed about warnings in the process. Say I make a typo, then the compiler emits a warning, then my terminal is flooded with info about tests not passing.
How would I prevent `doo` from running if the build is not without warnings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to convert ClojureScript compiler warnings into errors so that the build fails before `doo` can run.

> This is done at the compiler level by making use of `cljs.analyzer/with-warning-handlers`, for which there are [hooks in cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#custom-warning-handlers). Jake McCrary has a [good post](https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2015/12/19/clojurescript-treat-warnings-as-errors/) illustrating how to use this to invoke `(System/exit 1)`.

Perhaps this can be composed with `lein doo` to achieve the desired result.